# Blockchain.info API access

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

It's been a few weeks that I'm trying to get a Payments API access key from blockchain.info. However, their signup form returns Bad Url error. Am I the only one who is getting this issue? It's a very reputable website and I don't believe that it doesn't work.

Payments API
https://api.blockchain.info/customer/signup

Wallet API
https://www.blockchain.com/api/request